# Can't launch Google account

Tags: gnome

When I try to connect to my google account the gnome does not launch.

I reinstalled but always the same. I have also a tool that connects to license server al launch and it takes ages wich is no normal.
It seems to me as a something with net connection.

Thanks for your help
Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written is unclear, and will be difficult for this community to help resolve your issue. Can you please provide some additional information about what it is that you're trying to do. You mention that you're trying "to connect [your] Google account, the Gnome does not launch" I don't know what that means. Are you running in a Chrome browser? What "gnome" are you referring to? Finally, you mention an issue with a license server. If this is a separate issue (unrelated) then you should open a separate topic. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance and thanks for your suggestions. I try to explain better. I'm using ubuntu 23.04. When I want to connect to my google account I'm able to put my email but when I press submit the app greys and does nothing with the result I cant connect to my google account. I tried reinstalling gnome but no difference. I tried to add an image but I don't know how. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a new bug, possibly https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/2018656

Comment: What does it mean that the Gnome doesn't launch? You didn't clarify it in your comment.

Answer (score 5):

It's a common issue, I don't know about definite solution, but here what i did to bypass this bug.

1. Open terminal and enter this command : `WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center`
2. Online accounts window will pop up, keep the terminal open in background. Add your accound and press CTRL+C in terminal when you have finished adding your account.