# Can't seem to sign into Google Account

Tags: google, online-accounts, google-drive

I've and issue where I can't seem to log into google on my new installation of Ubuntu 23/10. I found it really useful on my old install which was the 22.04LTS but when I go to
Settings>Online Accounts
and click on the 'Google' option, I'm just getting a blank popup. Would really appreciate if someone could explain where I'm going wrong. Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Might be the same issue as https://askubuntu.com/a/1425273/231142

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pop-up window goes blank when adding Google account in GNOME Control Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424005/pop-up-window-goes-blank-when-adding-google-account-in-gnome-control-center)

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers here. For your particular issue, I'd check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1466656/cant-launch-google-account) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424005/pop-up-window-goes-blank-when-adding-google-account-in-gnome-control-center) for similar questions that match your symptoms. However, I ran into a second issue immediately afterward that I want to share here in case it comes up for you too.

As arturpio suggested, I was indeed having trouble with an account that has 2FA enabled. After entering my password, that dialog seemed to load forever. However, I wasn't exactly excited to disable 2FA, so I did a bit more digging.

[This reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/17aipt4/comment/k892opl/) in the same predicament tried something that hadn't occurred to me -- right click in the login dialog and hit "Reload." It immediately pushed me on to the 2FA step without any more trouble. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 google accounts. Two are not protected with 2-Step Verification (double question), one is activated with this feature.

Since the day the 2-Step Verification was activated, I can not connect (Ubuntu) Gnome to this Google account. The pop-up window freezes after password question and nothing happen.

I was using every feature I can find on Internet, nothing works. Finally I ask myself : why two account connect to Gnome without problem and only one freezes?

The one sole and unique difference between those 3 accounts was this 2-Step Verification. So, simply, I deactivated it in the account.  And, it solved the Ubuntu/Gnome connection problem instantaneously.

That is this. The solution is simple: do not use 2-Step Verification with Google...